# Extract Zip file and read the data inside the file in angular

Tags: angular, extract, unzip

I have a zip file which is uploaded using file input.I want to read the data from that zip file.Can anyone help me to read the data inside the zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jszip library- https://stuk.github.io/jszip/.

```
const jsZip = require('jszip');
  jsZip.loadAsync(fileList[0]).then((zip) => { // <----- HERE
    Object.keys(zip.files).forEach((filename) => { // <----- HERE
      zip.files[filename].async('string').then((fileData) => { // <----- HERE
         this.fileData = this.fileData + '**$$##$$**' + fileData;
      });
    });
  });
```

Source: [Reading zip file contents and assign it to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925056/reading-zip-file-contents-and-assign-it-to-local-variable)